# Xdnd drop support faulty implementation

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, xorg, drop

I have implemented a Xdnd drop support implementation in VTK some time ago. It was working great except with Thunar file manager. All other file managers were working fine at the time. We dismissed this limitation a Thunar bug at the time.

The feature I implemented was very simple:

- Set the window of the application to be XdndAware
- Receive the position message and respond that we are ready to receive
- Receive the drop mesage and request a selection
- Receive the selection notify and recover the URI
- Convert the URI into something we can work with

Nothing fancy, I did not even touch the list type.

Fast forward a few years and now dolphin users cannot drop files correctly into our application. The URI is always the first file dropped since dolphin was started. Restarting our application has no effect. No bug at all with pcmanfm.

This is not a dolphin bug and files can be dropped on blender or firefox from dolphin without issues.

So there must be a bug in our implementation, but I've been staring at the code for some time and everything I tried had no effect, except for breaking Xdnd support completely.

Here are the interesting part of the implementation:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vtkXRenderWindowInteractor::vtkXRenderWindowInteractor()
{
  this->Internal = new vtkXRenderWindowInteractorInternals;
  this->DisplayId = nullptr;
  this->WindowId = 0;
  this->KillAtom = 0;
  this->XdndSource = 0;
  this->XdndPositionAtom = 0;
  this->XdndDropAtom = 0;
  this->XdndActionCopyAtom = 0;
  this->XdndStatusAtom = 0;
  this->XdndFinishedAtom = 0;
}

[...]


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void vtkXRenderWindowInteractor::Enable()
{
  // avoid cycles of calling Initialize() and Enable()
  if (this->Enabled)
  {
    return;
  }

  // Add the event handler to the system.
  // If we change the types of events processed by this handler, then
  // we need to change the Disable() routine to match.  In order for Disable()
  // to work properly, both the callback function AND the client data
  // passed to XtAddEventHandler and XtRemoveEventHandler must MATCH
  // PERFECTLY
  XSelectInput(this->DisplayId, this->WindowId,
    KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | ExposureMask |
      StructureNotifyMask | EnterWindowMask | LeaveWindowMask | PointerMotionHintMask |
      PointerMotionMask);

  // Setup for capturing the window deletion
  this->KillAtom = XInternAtom(this->DisplayId, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
  XSetWMProtocols(this->DisplayId, this->WindowId, &this->KillAtom, 1);

  // Enable drag and drop
  Atom xdndAwareAtom = XInternAtom(this->DisplayId, "XdndAware", False);
  char xdndVersion = 5;
  XChangeProperty(this->DisplayId, this->WindowId, xdndAwareAtom, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace,
    (unsigned char*)&xdndVersion, 1);
  this->XdndPositionAtom = XInternAtom(this->DisplayId, "XdndPosition", False);
  this->XdndDropAtom = XInternAtom(this->DisplayId, "XdndDrop", False);
  this->XdndActionCopyAtom = XInternAtom(this->DisplayId, "XdndActionCopy", False);
  this->XdndStatusAtom = XInternAtom(this->DisplayId, "XdndStatus", False);
  this->XdndFinishedAtom = XInternAtom(this->DisplayId, "XdndFinished", False);

  this->Enabled = 1;

  this->Modified();
}

[...]

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void vtkXRenderWindowInteractor::DispatchEvent(XEvent* event)
{
  int xp, yp;

  switch (event->type)
  {
[...]

    // Selection request for drag and drop has been delivered
    case SelectionNotify:
    {
      // Sanity checks
      if (!event->xselection.property || !this->XdndSource)
      {
        return;
      }

      // Recover the dropped file
      char* data = nullptr;
      Atom actualType;
      int actualFormat;
      unsigned long itemCount, bytesAfter;
      XGetWindowProperty(this->DisplayId, event->xselection.requestor, event->xselection.property,
        0, LONG_MAX, False, event->xselection.target, &actualType, &actualFormat, &itemCount,
        &bytesAfter, (unsigned char**)&data);

      // Conversion checks
      if ((event->xselection.target != AnyPropertyType && actualType != event->xselection.target) ||
        itemCount == 0)
      {
        return;
      }

      // Recover filepaths from uris and invoke DropFilesEvent
      std::stringstream uris(data);
      std::string uri, protocol, hostname, filePath;
      std::string unused0, unused1, unused2, unused3;
      vtkNew<vtkStringArray> filePaths;
      while (std::getline(uris, uri, '\n'))
      {
        if (vtksys::SystemTools::ParseURL(
              uri, protocol, unused0, unused1, hostname, unused3, filePath, true))
        {
          if (protocol == "file" && (hostname.empty() || hostname == "localhost"))
          {
            // The uris can be crlf delimited, remove ending \r if any
            if (filePath.back() == '\r')
            {
              filePath.pop_back();
            }

            // The extracted filepath miss the first slash
            filePath.insert(0, "/");

            filePaths->InsertNextValue(filePath);
          }
        }
      }
      this->InvokeEvent(vtkCommand::DropFilesEvent, filePaths);
      XFree(data);

      // Inform the source the the drag and drop operation was sucessfull
      XEvent reply;
      memset(&reply, 0, sizeof(reply));

      reply.type = ClientMessage;
      reply.xclient.window = event->xclient.data.l[0];
      reply.xclient.message_type = this->XdndFinishedAtom;
      reply.xclient.format = 32;
      reply.xclient.data.l[0] = this->WindowId;
      reply.xclient.data.l[1] = itemCount;
      reply.xclient.data.l[2] = this->XdndActionCopyAtom;

      XSendEvent(this->DisplayId, this->XdndSource, False, NoEventMask, &reply);
      XFlush(this->DisplayId);
      this->XdndSource = 0;
    }
    break;


    case ClientMessage:
    {
      if (event->xclient.message_type == this->XdndPositionAtom)
      {
        // Drag and drop event inside the window

        // Recover the position
        int xWindow, yWindow;
        int xRoot = event->xclient.data.l[2] >> 16;
        int yRoot = event->xclient.data.l[2] & 0xffff;
        Window root = DefaultRootWindow(this->DisplayId);
        Window child;
        XTranslateCoordinates(
          this->DisplayId, root, this->WindowId, xRoot, yRoot, &xWindow, &yWindow, &child);

        // Convert it to VTK compatible location
        double location[2];
        location[0] = static_cast<double>(xWindow);
        location[1] = static_cast<double>(this->Size[1] - yWindow - 1);
        this->InvokeEvent(vtkCommand::UpdateDropLocationEvent, location);

        // Reply that we are ready to copy the dragged data
        XEvent reply;
        memset(&reply, 0, sizeof(reply));

        reply.type = ClientMessage;
        reply.xclient.window = event->xclient.data.l[0];
        reply.xclient.message_type = this->XdndStatusAtom;
        reply.xclient.format = 32;
        reply.xclient.data.l[0] = this->WindowId;
        reply.xclient.data.l[1] = 1; // Always accept the dnd with no rectangle
        reply.xclient.data.l[2] = 0; // Specify an empty rectangle
        reply.xclient.data.l[3] = 0;
        reply.xclient.data.l[4] = this->XdndActionCopyAtom;

        XSendEvent(this->DisplayId, event->xclient.data.l[0], False, NoEventMask, &reply);
        XFlush(this->DisplayId);
      }
      else if (event->xclient.message_type == this->XdndDropAtom)
      {
        // Item dropped in the window
        // Store the source of the drag and drop
        this->XdndSource = event->xclient.data.l[0];

        // Ask for a conversion of the selection. This will trigger a SelectioNotify event later.
        Atom xdndSelectionAtom = XInternAtom(this->DisplayId, "XdndSelection", False);
        XConvertSelection(this->DisplayId, xdndSelectionAtom, 
          XInternAtom(this->DisplayId, "UTF8_STRING", False), xdndSelectionAtom, this->WindowId,
          CurrentTime);
      }
      else if (static_cast<Atom>(event->xclient.data.l[0]) == this->KillAtom)
      {
        this->ExitCallback();
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}
[...]
```

And header:

```
#include "vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h"
#include "vtkRenderingUIModule.h" // For export macro
#include <X11/Xlib.h>             // Needed for X types in the public interface

class vtkCallbackCommand;
class vtkXRenderWindowInteractorInternals;

class VTKRENDERINGUI_EXPORT vtkXRenderWindowInteractor : public vtkRenderWindowInteractor
{
public:
  static vtkXRenderWindowInteractor* New();
  vtkTypeMacro(vtkXRenderWindowInteractor, vtkRenderWindowInteractor);
  void PrintSelf(ostream& os, vtkIndent indent) override;

  /**
   * Initializes the event handlers without an XtAppContext.  This is
   * good for when you don't have a user interface, but you still
   * want to have mouse interaction.
   */
  void Initialize() override;

  /**
   * Break the event loop on 'q','e' keypress. Want more ???
   */
  void TerminateApp() override;

  /**
   * Run the event loop and return. This is provided so that you can
   * implement your own event loop but yet use the vtk event handling as
   * well.
   */
  void ProcessEvents() override;

  ///@{
  /**
   * Enable/Disable interactions.  By default interactors are enabled when
   * initialized.  Initialize() must be called prior to enabling/disabling
   * interaction. These methods are used when a window/widget is being
   * shared by multiple renderers and interactors.  This allows a "modal"
   * display where one interactor is active when its data is to be displayed
   * and all other interactors associated with the widget are disabled
   * when their data is not displayed.
   */
  void Enable() override;
  void Disable() override;
  ///@}

  /**
   * Update the Size data member and set the associated RenderWindow's
   * size.
   */
  void UpdateSize(int, int) override;

  /**
   * Re-defines virtual function to get mouse position by querying X-server.
   */
  void GetMousePosition(int* x, int* y) override;

  void DispatchEvent(XEvent*);

protected:
  vtkXRenderWindowInteractor();
  ~vtkXRenderWindowInteractor() override;

  /**
   * Update the Size data member and set the associated RenderWindow's
   * size but do not resize the XWindow.
   */
  void UpdateSizeNoXResize(int, int);

  // Using static here to avoid destroying context when many apps are open:
  static int NumAppInitialized;

  Display* DisplayId;
  Window WindowId;
  Atom KillAtom;
  int PositionBeforeStereo[2];
  vtkXRenderWindowInteractorInternals* Internal;

  // Drag and drop related
  Window XdndSource;
  Atom XdndPositionAtom;
  Atom XdndDropAtom;
  Atom XdndActionCopyAtom;
  Atom XdndStatusAtom;
  Atom XdndFinishedAtom;

  ///@{
  /**
   * X-specific internal timer methods. See the superclass for detailed
   * documentation.
   */
  int InternalCreateTimer(int timerId, int timerType, unsigned long duration) override;
  int InternalDestroyTimer(int platformTimerId) override;
  ///@}

  void FireTimers();

  /**
   * This will start up the X event loop and never return. If you
   * call this method it will loop processing X events until the
   * application is exited.
   */
  void StartEventLoop() override;

private:
  vtkXRenderWindowInteractor(const vtkXRenderWindowInteractor&) = delete;
  void operator=(const vtkXRenderWindowInteractor&) = delete;
};

#endif
```

The complete file can be seen here:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Rendering/UI/vtkXRenderWindowInteractor.cxx

You can follow my train of thoughts and debugs here:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/f3d/f3d/-/issues/228

To test this code, a simple way is to use F3D has it is using the dropped file, but a simple VTK application should work as well:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/f3d/f3d

Comment: Seems like you never initialize the `PositionBeforeStereo` data member (however I never see it used). Anyone kind of reading of this member (even unintentional by say copying a `vtkXRenderWindowInteractor` object through its default copy ctor) would mean undefined behaviour. Which could do anything. This is likely not the issue here, but hey, why not exclude such dangers to ease your debugging :) Have you tried run UB-san on your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Current Dolphin issue

From some testing, the issue is with the preparation and sending of the `XdndFinished` `ClientMessage` back to the drag and drop source when handling the `SelectionNotify` event.

Instead of:

```
reply.xclient.window = event->xclient.data.l[0];
```

the line should be:

```
reply.xclient.window = this->XdndSource;
```

This aligns the `XClientMessageEvent` `window` member with the target window argument to `XSendEvent`. This is probably a simple copy-paste error, as `xclient` isn't valid for the `SelectionNotify` event type. Most likely the actual value of `window` was not previously being checked, but that has been changed recently, hence the error.

The [spec](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/XDND/) covers this quite well, and also raises a couple of other things to consider:

- For `data.l[1]`: "Bit 0 is set if the current target accepted the drop and successfully performed the accepted drop action. (new in version 5)", so using `itemCount` as a value will technically be incorrect whenever the count is even
- If the handling of `XdndPosition` doesn't need to actually track where the current position is (i.e. if you are just using the entire window as a drop target), you may be able to get away with sending the `XdndStatus` in response to the `XdndEnter` message

#### Previous Thunar issue

Looking into this further, I did some troubleshooting regarding the previous issue with Thunar, and it boils down to the code handling `XdndDrop` assuming that the format of the incoming data can be converted to `UTF8_STRING`. This [diff](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/commit/6a65341e14bc7745c52fe86fe53be08dbd682dd9) for GLFW handles almost the exact same issue.

If, when handling the `XdndEnter` message, you inspect the values of `xclient.data.l[2]` through `xclient.data.l[4]` you can see that Dolphin reports supporting the following formats:

- `text/uri-list`
- `text/x-moz-url`
- `text/plain`

whereas Thunar only supports the following:

- `text/uri-list`

The simplest solution is to:

- Keep track of a supported format when handling `XdndEnter`
- Provide this format to `XConvertSelection` when handling `XdndDrop` (instead of `UTF8_STRING`)
- Handle the format appropriately when handling the `SelectionNotify` event

To be more complete, if bit 0 of `xclient.data.l[1]` is set on the `XdndEnter` message, you should get the `XdndTypeList` property of the drag and drop source window and based the format selection on that, instead of the formats contained in the message itself.

Comment: You are awesome ! I'll try this as soon as I find the time. Enjoy your bounty !

Comment: Everything you said was correct. If you feel like a review, see here: 
https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/merge_requests/8086